# How to combine a menu and submenu into one Hamburger with Tiles, Bootstrap and jsp

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, twitter-bootstrap-3, tiles

I am working on a project which uses `Tiles`, `Struts2` and `Bootstrap` with our `jsp` pages.  We have a base tiles file `tiles.xml` which contains the following code.

```
<definition name="baseLayout" template="/WEB-INF/pages/layout.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="title"         value="Regulatory Action Tracking" />
    <put-attribute name="header"        value="/WEB-INF/pages/header.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="navigation"    value="/WEB-INF/pages/navigation/mainNav.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name='subnav'        value='/WEB-INF/pages/navigation/navEmpty.jsp' />
    <put-attribute name="content"       value="" />
    <put-attribute name="footer"        value="/WEB-INF/pages/footer.jsp" />
</definition>
```

This code is used to put the main menu on each page using the code shown below which is contained in `mainNav.jsp`.

```
<div id="navigate">
<button class="navbar-toggle collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-main">
    <span class="sr-only">Mobile Menu Button</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
```

```
<nav id="menu" role="navigation">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar-responsive-collapse" id="navbar-main" style="height: 1px;">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav yamm">
                <li><a href="/rat/home.action">Home</a></li>    
                <li><a href="/rat/rule/ruleSummary.action">Rules</a></li>
                <li><a href="/rat/fiveYearReview/fiveYearSummary.action">5 Year Review</a></li>           
                <li><a href="/rat/logout.action" onclick="window.close();">Logout</a></li>                  
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My page adds a sub-menu by setting the subnav attribute using the `tiles-admin.xml` and `adminNav.jsp` files shown below.

```
    <definition name="employee" extends="baseLayout">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="Regulatory Action Tracking, Employee page" />
    <put-attribute name='subnav' value='/WEB-INF/pages/navigation/adminNav.jsp' />      
    <put-attribute name="content" value="/WEB-INF/pages/admin/employeeMaint.jsp" />
</definition>

<nav id="menu" role="navigation">
<section id="subnav" >      
    <div class="rowNav">
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar-responsive-collapse" id="navbar-main" style="height: 1px;">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav yamm">
              <li><a href="/rat/admin/refQuestion.action">Review Admin</a></li>             
              <li><a href="/rat/admin/employee.action">Employee Admin</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>      
</section>
```

The menu and submenu work fine with desktop size screens but when it displays on a mobile size screen `Bootstrap` only puts the main menu in the "hamburger" menu.  Is there a way to include the submenu items in the hamburger responsively?  I tagged this with `jQuery` and `javascript` because I think I may have to use one of them to fix this.  Any help will be appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do it with `jQuery`.  I don't know if it is the best way.  I put the following code at the top of my page.

```
    <script src="/rat/javascript/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>    

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        if ($(window).width() < 768) {
            $(".main-menu").append($(".move"));
        } else {
            $(".sub-menu").append($(".move"));
        }
    });

    $(window).resize(function () {
        if ($(window).width() < 768) {
            $(".main-menu").append($(".move"));
        } else {
            $(".sub-menu").append($(".move"));
        }
    });
</script>
```

I then added a `main-menu` class to my main menu.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav yamm main-menu">
```

Lastly I added a `sub-menu` class to my sub menu and a `move` class to each of the elements in the sub menu list.

```
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav yamm sub-menu">
                <DNRTags:AccessRoles roleList="System Administrator">
                    <li class="move"><a href="/rat/admin/refQuestion.action">Review Admin</a></li>                                                                  
                    <li class="move"><a href="/rat/admin/employee.action">Employee Admin</a></li>
                </DNRTags:AccessRoles>                  
            </ul>
```